# jquery dialog hoverintent causes flicker

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a dialog that will popup when an element is hovered over.  The implementation utilizes hoverintent to open and close the dialog.  Using jqueryui 1.12, the dialog flickers and doesnt stay open.  Recently updated the open dialog method to utilize object which will display the dialog next to the object (which was a required change).

```
    HOVERLINKDELAY: 100
    $("span.memberNameLink").hoverIntent({ over: claimstatus.memberOver, out: claimstatus.memberOut, interval: c.HOVERLINKDELAY });

    memberOver: function (e) {
let claimid = $(this).attr('data-claimid');
let rowData = $(claimstatus.claimsGrid).getRowData(claimid);
claimstatus.openHoverDialog('Claim\'s Member Info: ' + rowData.MemberName.stripTags('span'), 400, 220, e);
let html = '<dl><dt>System ID:</dt><dd>' + rowData.PatientId + '</dd></dl>';
html += '<dl><dt>External Member ID:</dt><dd>' + rowData.ExtMemberID + '</dd></dl>';
html += '<dl><dt>Patient Account Number:</dt><dd>' + rowData.PatientAcctNumber + '</dd></dl>';
html += '<dl><dt>SSN:</dt><dd>' + rowData.SSNumber + '</dd></dl>';
$('#dialogHoverForm').html(html);
    },


    memberOut: function () {
claimstatus.closeHoverDialog();
    },


    openHoverDialog: function (title, width, height, overEvent) {
$("#dialog-hover").dialog({
    position: { my: "center", at: "center", of: overEvent },
    title: title,
    width: width,
    height: height,
    modal: false,
    draggable: true,
    resizable: true,
    closeOnEscape: false,
    open: function (event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", this.parentNode).hide(); }
});
    },
```

What would be a viable way to prevent the dialog box from 'flickering'?

Comment: I ended up adding a timeout and that seemed to remedy the issue.  With the below change, the dialog will appear for 2 seconds before closing.        `setTimeout(function () { claimstatus.closeHoverDialog(); }, 2000);`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a timeout and that seemed to remedy the issue.  With the below change, the dialog will appear for 2 seconds before closing.

```
  setTimeout(function () { claimstatus.closeHoverDialog(); }, 2000);
```